# ES reversed filtering

Tags: elasticsearch

Pardon the title, not sure how better to describe the problem.

Anyway, I have a table with `entries(id, name, age, ..dynamic fields)` and `filter_groups(id, filters[])`

Each filter group as a list of filters of the form `{filter, field, value}` that is used client-side to filter an HTML table of `entries`

Exmaples:

```
[{ filter: 'less_than', field: 'age' value: 10 },
{filter: 'is', field: 'name' value: "john doe" }]
```

If I wanted to fetch all the entries matching a particular filter group, it seems fairly straightforward to construct the query and send it to ES using the filters.

However, if you reverse the situation and given an `entry` want to fetch all the `filter_groups` whose filters match the `entry`, how would you go about doing this?

Thanks

Comment: If you're using ES 5.x, you should investigate the [`percolate` query](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-percolate-query.html) otherwise you should check the [Percolator API](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/2.4/search-percolate.html).

Comment: Perfect, this was exactly what I was looking for.